# What are the fuel system pressure and temperature requirements of a Williams FJ44 engine?

Tags: turbofan, fuel-systems

For my university project, I am designing the fuel supply and control system of an aircraft that use Williams International FJ44-3A engine. However, after scouring through its type certificate datasheets in [EASA](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/TCDS%20IM%20E%20016%20%20issue%2013_210721.pdf) and [FAA](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/WebSearchDefault?SearchView&Query=FJ44&SearchOrder=1&SearchMax=1000&SearchWV=1&SearchFuzzy=0&Start=1&Count=1000&vs=Curr#), I can't find the fuel pressure and temperature requirement inside. The EASA TCDS said that the fuel requirements are inside the installation instruction. But I can't seems to find them after searching the number of the installation instruction.

Comment: actually, the school project is to do preliminary design of fuel supply, cabin pressure, and firefighting system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FJ44 uses an internal mechanical pump to provide fuel at high pressure to the engine. At least on the Cessna Citation aircraft that use the engine, the fuel comes from the primary ejector pumps which are submerged in fuel in each engine feed bay (lowest point in the fuel system, holds about eight gals on the Citation Mustang, for example).

The pump utilizes a small jet of high-pressure “motive flow” fuel (from the respective engine fuel pumps). The fuel passes through a venturi, pulls a larger low-pressure flow of fuel from the feed bay, and pumps it back to the engine. Some of the resulting flow also provides motive flow to the scavenge ejector pumps. The primary ejector pump has no moving parts. It operates whenever motive flow is available.

The Citations also have boost pumps that can be used for engine starting, in a low fuel supply pressure condition and for fuel transfer. If the system for the FJ44-equipped aircraft is anything like the Mustang (which uses Pratt and Whitney engines), the boost pumps engage at 4.65 psig and disengage at 6.5 psig. That however is the pressure supplied to the **inlet** of the primary ejector pump. If the pressure on the motive side of the pump (coming from the engine) remains too low, things will probably get interesting rather quickly for the pilot(s).

So, the answer to your question is that fuel pressure to the engine is not specified, but can be inferred from the boost pump pressure-activated switches. The system simply requires fuel in the tanks and in the engine mechanical pump. As long as those two are there, the venturi effect takes care of the rest. The boost pumps are used when that system is not supplying enough fuel, for whatever reason.

Fuel heating is done by running fuel through an oil heat exchanger. This cools the oil using the fuel, and transfers the heat to the tanks. Temperatures for the Cessna CJ-1, -2, and -3 are shown [here](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2009/12/23/E9-30436/special-conditions-cessna-aircraft-company-model-525c-high-fuel-temperature). It is interesting to note the document shows the FAA was forced to reconsider its certification requirements for fuel tanks because the maximum temperature of heated fuel being returned to the tanks in Cessna's design exceeds what was before that the maximum temperature required for certification testing of fuel tanks for hot weather operation.

[Source: Cessna Citation CJ4 Specification and Description](https://www.tadistributors.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/SD-CJ4-Unit-0200-to-TBD-2015-Oct.pdf)

[image: Depiction of an ejector pump]

Comment: It is a very useful answer, thank you! Do you know what is the model of the boost pump and the flow ejector pump they use? I may be able to deduce the pressure and temperature requirements using those information.

Comment: The ejector pump is just a venturi system. I have no idea what the part numbers are, nor if different aircraft use different part numbers. For the boost pumps you will have to search for parts catalogs and/or maintenance manuals for specific aircraft. Operating manuals will tell you what the minimum pressure is supposed to be before the boost pump engages. In general this type of system requires low pressure but high volume, as the engine injectors require much smaller volume but much higher pressure to feed the engine's combustion requirements.

Comment: I added more of the info you need to my answer from another source.